# Copy a Cinnamon configuration

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I have recently installed Linux Mint 18.3 on my second computer. I copied the home folder, including some various configuration folders, `.cinnamon`, `.gconf`, and all those from my first computer. When I logged into my second computer, I expected the desktop background, keyboard shortcuts, and all that, to work exactly as on my first computer, since I copied the configuration!

Instead, I was greeted with the default "You started Cinnamon for the first time" configuration, the default linux mint desktop background, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution from another question:

- [Where keyboard shortcuts settings are stored?](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=159521)

For example:

```
  # export
      dconf dump /org/cinnamon/ > file.txt
  
  # import
      dconf load /org/cinnamon/ < file.txt
```

I suggest you using the `dconf editor` to browse the key paths and explore your setup.  A surprising number of things I haven't been able to find turned-up in the `~/.config/dconf/user` database.

- `sudo apt install dconf-editor`

The keyboard shortcuts live here:

```
 /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/
```

When you want absolutely everything, use `dconf-editor` to pick the correct "everything" you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. You could have used a disk imaging program, like Clonezilla to backup that Linux Mint partition from one computer to an external drive, then, restore it to the new computer. Simple and easy!
2. There is an app called Aptik to migrate system settings and configuration to a fresh install of Linux Mint. Read more about it [here](https://teejeetech.in/aptik/).

I think that only copying system files won't do nothing.