# Switching over from Kubuntu to Debian

Tags: linux, debian, kubuntu

I would like to know if there are any special precautions I should take when attempting to move over from Kubuntu to Debian?

I'm not really worried about configs or anything like that I just want all my files on my disk such as important VM images.

Can I just backup my entire Home folder?

Also I have created snapshots of my whole OS using Timeshift to an external HDD (Wow now I sound like an idiot because I basically already backed up the whole thing)

Thanks

Comment: Somewhat similar [question](https://superuser.com/q/1312198/880618) but since you're going from Kubuntu to Debian it might not apply.

Comment: Hello! Please add information regarding your partitioning scheme. Do you have only one partition? Do you have different ones? Do you have a seperate home partition? Also, where are those VM images stored? Please supply enough information so we can help you with your issue.

Comment: Hi @Fanatique i am going to do a clean install of debian on my SSD. I want to completely format all data and start fresh. My virtual machine images are under a virtualbox folder as I am using virtualbox for virtualization. I am using Timeshift with Rsync so I expect the entire system to be backed up. I can also browse the backups from within Timeshift. I assume I can just install timeshift on my debian install and then browse and copy data over as needed

Comment: This might be useful in reusing everything in Home when you reinstall: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ui5jBdTIuyI